# Building JAX-WS project with maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, jax-ws

I tried to build the project https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws
but I got these errors:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-bom:pom:2.3.1-b171012.0423 in jvnet-nexus-releases (https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/) @ line 208, column 25
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-bom:pom:2.3.1-b171012.0423 in https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jvnet-nexus-releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri-bom:2.3.1-SNAPSHOT, /Users/lopes/Downloads/metro-jax-ws-master/jaxws-ri/boms/bom/pom.xml, line 208, column 25
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 2 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri-bom:2.3.1-SNAPSHOT (/Users/lopes/Downloads/metro-jax-ws-master/jaxws-ri/boms/bom/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-bom:pom:2.3.1-b171012.0423 in jvnet-nexus-releases (https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/) @ line 208, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri-bom-ext:2.3.1-SNAPSHOT (/Users/lopes/Downloads/metro-jax-ws-master/jaxws-ri/boms/bom-ext/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-bom:pom:2.3.1-b171012.0423 in https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jvnet-nexus-releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri-bom:2.3.1-SNAPSHOT, /Users/lopes/Downloads/metro-jax-ws-master/jaxws-ri/boms/bom/pom.xml, line 208, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: Those sources are old and probably refer to Java.net as a repository. That has been taken down, but many artifacts are on maven central so you just need those instead.

Comment: @enLopes Did you check that you have also the parent project `<relativePath>boms/bom-ext/pom.xml</relativePath>` also available or did i check the wrong pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

If it does not help delete directory

```
{yourHomeDir}/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-bom
```

Comment: @enLopes please check that it still complains exactly this: **Could not find artifact org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-bom:pom:2.3.1-b171012.0423** and not any oher jar/pom or so.

Comment: @enLopes ok, i'll check further with the same pom. Do you have that parent project also in your env?